# how to stop height of fluid grid element from breaking layout

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I'm building a site using a normal css grid layout, not "grid" but by using percentages for the width of the elements. it goes from 100% on mobile, to 50%, to 33%, to 25%. 1 column, 2 column, 3 column, 4 column respectively.

I'm pulling in images in wordpress using an api. I don't have full control over the image sizes though. Some images are smaller, and some images are really big.

say my code for example is

```
.span_1_of_4 {
width:100%;
}
```

at higher pixels, its

```
.span_1_of_4 {
width:50%;
}
```

at higher pixels, its

```
.span_1_of_4 {
width:33%;
}
```

at higher pixels, its

```
.span_1_of_4 {
width:25%;
}
```

most images pulled in amount to 500px in height. some are under and a few here and there are over 500px;

When the larger images are pulled in, they stretch out the article (.span_1_of_4) and it turns breaks the whole layout. It pushes down the elements underneath it. Is there any way to code in css that will not allow the article to go over 500px. I can deal with the images being smaller, it doesn't break the layout if one of the article is smaller than the others, only breaks it if its larger than the other ones.

Probably a very simple question, but pulling my hair out trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
max-width: 500px;
```

to your columns.